# The "CPU Configurations" option does not appear in the "Advanced" tab of my BIOS

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, hardware-virtualization

I need to enable virtualization on my PC for Operating Systems class at the college, but the virtualization option does not appear in the BIOS, even though it is theoretically compatible, below is some information about my PC (which is quite old even):

**Operating system:** Windows 10 Pro 64-bit 
**Processor:** Intel Celeron 847 1.10GHz 
**RAM Memory:** 4GB 
**HD:** 500GB 
**Graphics Card:** Intel HD Graphics (even integrated) 
**Motherboard:** Manufacturer-MSI, Product-C847IS-P33 (MS-7836), Version-1.0
**Detail:** This is what it shows when I use the command in CMD, because in the MSI Live Update 6 application it shows- **"MotherBoard BIOS version / 1.12"**. Another important thing is that in my BIOS it still shows that my Windows is 8.

**Well, if you can help me with a solution that is quick and easy I will be very grateful...Thanks in advance!**

Comment: My motherboard isn't "C847MS-E33" ... It is "C847IS-P33"

Comment: Apologies for the sub-part mistake. Same forum says a BIOS update might fix this.   https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=167266.0

Comment: Do you know of a safer way to update bios other than by flash?

Comment: That depends on the board. I have found the best way for my own machines is a bios EXE file that begins in Windows and finishes via a BIOS initiated update. Other than that I cannot say.

Comment: Thank you very much, I updated the bios (I almost killed my PC) but in the end everything worked out. The only problem is that now I can't get into the bios, but at least virtualization is enabled ...

Comment: If I post the answer here, will you find that helpful ?

Comment: Yes, it would help a lot

Comment: when I restart the pc the MSI logo appears but nothing appears about "pressing any button to enter the bios", and if I press f11 (I pressed this in the previous version of the bios) nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That computer supports hardware virtualization. See:

https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=167266.0

You will need to update the BIOS to be able to set the option.

From the same forum, to enter and view BIOS settings, try the following:

> Press the "Delete" key while the system is booting up to enter the
>   BIOS. There is normally a message similar to "Press Del to enter
>   SETUP," but it can flash by quickly. On rare occasions, "F2" may be
>   the BIOS key.

Comment: already updated the bios. I just can't get into the bios to see how some settings are

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to fix this for your particular machine. I will keep looking

Comment: I added a comment to my answer for viewing BIOS to assist

Comment: thank you very much, i also have no idea why this happens, maybe it is a defense mechanism of the pc for me never to enter the bios lol

Comment: before performing the update the key I used to enter the bios was f11

Comment: but most of the time I used the advanced boot of windows 10 to enter the uefi settings, but it is also not working ... It restarts the pc and goes straight